# What does the energy of the electron in the energy level of an atom really mean?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, atomic-physics, orbitals

I am confused about the meaning of the energy of the electron in the energy level of the atom. How does an electron have a higher energy in a higher energy level and at the same time, it can be stripped of easier from the atom? And I also have a great confusion about the concept of the negative-valued energy of the electron.

Answer (score 0):

Witho8t any math, pure Intuatively, the only real thing that matters is the difference in energy.

The negative sign is just convention, and shows us that this is an attractive force and that positive work would need to be done to seperate the particles.

Imagine we have a potential well, to "release the electron" we want to electron to be at  the top of the Well, call this "E=0" with all other E values negative. If an electron has a higher energy, it is closer to the top of the Well  and thus requires less energy to get to the top as the difference in energy is lower

Answer (score 0):

In the opposite to the previous answer, the negative sign is not completely a convention. The kinetic energy of an electron is always positive, in a potential a free electron is scattered so that the state is lower in energy : this negative sign means that a positive kinetic energy should be provided for ionizing the particle.

The discrete energy levels are due to the fact that the state of an electron in a potential should be absolutely normalized, only some functions in this case satisfy this condition while the other states are forbidden creating a discrete distribution of the energy called energy levels.